# Connecting to SQL Server using Windows authentication by multiple users through Client-Server App

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, connection-string

Need help with connecting to SQL Server using Windows authentication by different users logging in to the clients using their domain account.  We have thousands of users and is there a easy way to use a specific AD service account even though users login to these client machines using their windows account. I see some examples of that online if using IIS. But we need this to work with a client server app.  Please help if there is a workaround. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would either provision SQL Logins for the AD Groups containing the users, or (less secure) use a SQL Login with user/name and password embedded in the application configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the response David! Creating AD group is one option but since its thousands of users and hard to manage, wondering if there is a easy way to use a specific AD account and impersonate.